# Is there an alternative to round a number in Apache Velocity without using MathTools?

Tags: velocity

I need to round a quantity in Apache Velocity, but it is supposed I'm not allow to change pom.xml at work, so, is there an alternative to skip `MathTools`?

I tried this example:

```
#set($String = "abc")
$String.format("%.2f", $val)
```

but it's not working,
Any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget an hash sign before `set`? The following is working for me:

```
#set($val=0.1294)
#set($String = "abc")
$String.format("%.2f", $val)
```

Output:

```
0.13
```

Comment: #set($val=0.1294)
 #set($String = "abc")
 #set($value = $String.format("%.2f", $val))
 
 <text align="left">Value: </text>
 <text align="right">$value</text>

I tried this and still not working

Comment: Your code works for me. Which version of Java and of Velocity are you using?